# Running threejs on IE 9 failing because of Float32Array

Tags: internet-explorer, three20

I'm writing a threejs demo that MUST run on pretty much all browsers - particularly IE down to IE9.

It looks like IE 9 should at least be able to run the Canvas Demos but I'm getting a Float32Array Javascript error.

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this somewhere but my searches have yielded nothing so far.

I should say that I'm a webdev beginner (although experienced programmer) and that I'm running an IE 9 instance on the virtualising service [Spoon.net](https://www.spoon.net/Browsers/).  IE10 works well with threejs through this service.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [so]! I'm not too familiar with Three.js, but IE9 doesn't support typed arrays (e.g. `Int8Array`, `Float32Array`, etc.).

Comment: hi Quantas. Yes, I see that.  There do seem to be some TypedArray implementations out there but thus far they have not worked for me.  Part of my problem is that I'm a graphics programmer who's literally picking up Javascript for the first time - I don't really know what I'm doing if I have to stray from the straight and narrow :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a late answer. But for reference, inexorabletash provides a polyfill that you can find on github:
https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/typedarray.js

It adds Float32Array support to IE 9. This way, you won't add WebGL support to IE9, but you will get rid of the Float32Array error.